# how to post on google plus page stream using php/curl?

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-plus

I want to post on google plus page stream using php, I checked google plus api but didn't found anything, read a post where it was saying that you can't post because google only provided read permission. When I googled I saw nextscripts SANP API to post on social networks.

If google only provided read permissions then how nextscripts is able to post?

SNAP is a paid API & I want to create my own code to do the same.

Is there anything I am missing. please guide me.

Comment: have you checked this answer ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236666/how-can-auto-post-to-google-plus-in-php

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** There is no way to create a post that appears in a Google+ stream.

**Medium answer**: Google doesn't provide an API to post to a "normal" user's page. There are APIs that allow a website to let a user post something, and they can suggest text to post, but the user must take an explicit action. There have been attempts to use unauthorized APIs to do this, but they try to intercept the above procedure and aren't reliable. Depending on your exact needs, there are other alternatives as well.

**Long answer**: Depending on your exact needs, there may be some APIs which can help. **But** keep in mind they only apply to specific, sometimes very narrow, circumstances:

*Are you trying to post to a page, not a user?* There is the Google+ Page API which is available to partners only. This may be what the netxtscripts SNAP API is using - I don't know. This is what HootSuite uses, for example. You can request access at https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup, but they don't approve many applicants.

*Are you trying to post on behalf of a  Google Apps user for other users in the same domain to see?* If so, there is the Domains API at https://developers.google.com/+/domains/

*Are trying to post an activity or action? Like the user listening to a song or eating at a restaurant?* You may benefit from App Activities with the Moments API. These don't go directly into the stream, but are available through Search, in the user's profile in some limited ways, and they can reshare them into the stream if they wish. https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities

*Let a user post to their stream from a web page?* This still requires specific action by the user, so they have to approve what you're saying, but you can use something like normal share, +1, or interactive post buttons. https://developers.google.com/+/features/interactive-posts

*You just want your server to post a plain old normal message to a normal user's stream without a person having to do anything?* You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is still no  way to post on a Google+ stream using an API. For details on what you can currently do with the limited API you can look at [Google+ api](https://developers.google.com/+/api/)

There is an issue request for this from as far back as 2011:    [Write access to the streams](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41&q=stream&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)